# Regex: How to remove a substring that is bounded by certain characters?

Tags: java, regex

I'm not sure what the appropriate regex expression would be for this:

```
String s = "[Don't remove] Don't remove [Remove | Don't remove]";
```

I want to remove everything in between [ and | but not [ and ]. So the output is:

```
"[Don't remove] Don't remove Don't remove]"
```

I tried doing this,

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\|", "");
```

but I end up getting something like this.

```
"Don't remove]"
```

Now I'm at a lost. I'm still new to regular expressions and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ngated character class `[^\[|]*` that will not allow matching any other `[` and `|` in between `[` and `|`:

```
String s = "[Don't remove] Don't remove [Remove | Don't remove]";
s = s.replaceAll("\\[[^\\[|]*\\|", "");
System.out.println(s); // => [Don't remove] Don't remove  Don't remove]
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F8GSx3/1) and an [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/Yu7Wqy).

**Details**

- `\\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^\\[|]*` - a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any 0+ chars other than a `[` and `|`
- `\\|` - a literal `|` symbol.